# Dager Hilt with Realm database

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, realm, dagger-hilt

Has anyone used Dagger Hilt with Realm database. I get an initialization problem. Perhaps the above solution will work.

Error ->

> Modules that need to be instantiated by Hilt must have a visible, empty constructor.
> [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.
> Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)`

MyModule ->

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class LocalDataSourceModule(context: Context) {
    
init {
        Realm.init(context)
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideLocalDataSource(realm: Realm): LocalDataSource = LocalDataSourceImpl(realm)

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRealm(configuration: RealmConfiguration): Realm =
        try {
            Realm.getDefaultInstance()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Realm.getInstance(configuration)
        }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRealmConfiguration(): RealmConfiguration = RealmConfiguration.Builder().build()
}
```

MyApp ->

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class BaseApplication : Application() {

    lateinit var girlComponent: GirlComponent
        private set

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())

        girlComponent = DaggerGirlComponent.builder().localDataSourceModule(
            LocalDataSourceModule(applicationContext)
        ).build()

    }
}
```

Comment: Never used Hilt, but the error is saying your module doesn't have a no-arg constructor, which it doesn't.  In the module remove the constructor argument, and either init realm elsewhere or in `provideRealm` function by passing a `Context` as a parameter and returns `Realm` like any other dependency you'd create.

Comment: then i get it  error: @Provides methods must return a value (not void)
    public final void provideRealmContext(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this may work. Hilt can inject the Application Context. Checkout
[@ApplicationContext](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#predefined-qualifiers)

```
import android.content.Context
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
import io.realm.Realm
import io.realm.RealmConfiguration
import javax.inject.Singleton

@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object RealmModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesRealmDatabase(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context
    ): Realm {
        Realm.init(context)
        val realmConfiguration = RealmConfiguration
            .Builder()
            .name("Tsavo Project")
            .build()
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration)
        return Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideRealm(@ApplicationContext context: Context): Realm =
    try {
        Realm.init(context)
        Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Realm.getInstance(provideRealmConfig())
    }

private fun provideRealmConfig(): RealmConfiguration = RealmConfiguration.Builder().build()
```